# Moving box with chapter number on margin

Tags: margins, page-numbering, boxes

I need to make some sort of moving shape with chapter number inside which will be moving with scrolling pages on twosided document.
Something like this:

[image: description]

Which package can provide me some help to implement this or it is even possible to do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I would say, of course you can do this, e.g. with TikZ. But please provide what you've got so far.

Comment: This example was not created in latex, it is showing just what I need to do in my document. My document has 30 pages, 2 sections which first one contains 10 subsections and 2nd has just 2. I need to put this box with '1' symbol on it which will be moving down with scrolling pages to second section then it changes to '2'.